# Delphi 10.4 Sydney: How can I build and run an Android application with SDK/NDK version different from the official one?

Tags: android, delphi, sdk, android-ndk

We are currently migrating from Delphi version **10.2** to **10.4.2.** 
We ran into a problem with an android application: apparently, *Delphi 10.4 no longer supports android 4.4.2 kitkat.*

Embrarcadero support suggested us to follow this blog and try to replace SDK and NDK with the older versions certified for Delphi 10.2: https://delphiworlds.com/2020/09/manual-android-sdk-ndk-install-delphi/

We have carried out several tests and have managed to build and run a simple application using Delphi 10.4 on a tablet with Android 4.4.2.
Unfortunately we still have a problem: when we tried to add a TClientDataset (or anything else that would need **MidasLib**) to our test application, we got a lot of compilation errors.

By following the tips found on "https://github.com/grijjy/JustAddCode/issues/2", we have managed to reduce the errors to six errors (You can see them in the second attached file "Post_fix_errors_log.txt"), but still cannot successfully build the application.

The last step with which we managed to reduce errors to just 1 was to replace the file "**libmidas.a**" located in "\Lib\android\release" folder, with the one we had on Delphi D25, but there is still that one error preventing us to successfully build the app.
The error is the following:
*

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Work\PlatformSDKs\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lc++_static
C:\Work\PlatformSDKs\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lc++abi
[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

Does anyone have any idea how we could build an application using "MidasLib" with Delphi 10.4.2 and make it run on android 4.4.2?
Is that even possible?

Comment: Another, perhaps easier, way forward might be to use an older Delphi version when you compile targeting an older Android version.

Comment: "Is that even possible?" No - as you have discovered, the midas libraries are built using a later platform version in the NDK and it makes them incompatible with the older platforms. I suggest using FireDAC (e.g. TFDMemTable) instead of TClientDataset

Comment: @MatthiasB Which is really the only stable way to do it.

Comment: @Dave Already tried using TFDMemTable, but the application is a DataSnap Client, which means it will need midas anyway.

Comment: @Matthias probably what we will end up doing